# How to test the importance of environmental variables to a crocodile when selecting a nest site (geographic location)

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, ecology

I don't have a background in stats so please bear with me. I'm developing a study on where saltwater crocodiles nest. I want to see how variables such as slope of the bank, sun exposure, vegetation cover etc. influence the nest location, i.e., how significant a particular variable is in relation to the nest location. Based on my limited knowledge, a multiple regression analysis can be used to understand the relationship between a single dependent variable and multiple independent variable, which sounds ideal in this case. However, "location" doesn't really have a numerical value which I can compare with values for some of the dependent variables above, which I guess is my main problem. The aim of the study is to try and develop a habitat suitability assessment model for crocodile nests. Any suggestions on which potential models/statistical tests I can use to do this would be super appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, I think it's great that you are thinking of statistics before collecting your data! Second, what kind of measurements or observations are you planning to collect about your variable of interest (location of nests)? Maybe you are going to canvass a certain area and record each nest sighting and the attributes you mentioned (slope, sun exposure etc.)?

Comment: @Sointu thanks so much! Yes, exactly. The plan is to conduct boat surveys around an area of wetland. Once nests are found we plan to record these characteristics like measuring the slope of the bank to the water, distance from the nest to vegetation, sun exposure using hemispherical photographs of the site etc.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry your question got closed, I do think it's clear at least after your edit. About your design - would it be possible to somehow also gather observations of "no nests" and record the attributes you mentioned for those? For instance maybe you could decide to observe every riverbank "slot" at certain intervals and record whether there is a nest and the attributes too. Then you could have a nest vs. no nest dependent variable in a regression model and your attributes as predictors. There must be other ways but I can't think of one now...

Comment: Oh that's a really good idea, I hadn't thought of it like that. I will experiment with some dummy data and see how I can build that up. Thanks so much!